# CSS: vertical-align an <a> within a floated <div> not working

Tags: html, css

I have an a `<a>` inside of a `<div>`. Is there any reason that `vertical-align: middle;` won't work here?

Also I can't adjust the `padding` or `margin` of the `<a>` element.

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
       <a href="#">Test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation {
background: red;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
}

.container {
background: blue;
float: left;
clear: none;
height: 100%;
text-align: center; // this works
vertical-align: middle; // this does not work.
}

.container a {
}
```

Comment: [This article](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/) sums up how the vertical-align property works - it will not affect a div since it is a block level element. You could try setting your <a> tag to have a line-height equal to its parent container. Here is a jsfiddle that shows a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/XdX4d/2/

Comment: also, `vertical-align` does not align an element's children. it only aligns that particular element. if you apply `vertical-align` to the `a` tag, you'll see that it IS affected, just not that much because of the line height.

Answer (score 2):

> "Is there any reason that vertical-align: middle; won't work here?"

Yes, the reason is that 'vertical-align' will only align something vertically within its parent if said parent is either a table cell (td or th) or if said object is set to `display: table-cell` in css.

Google 'vertical align with CSS' to finds all sorts of examples and tutorials and workarounds. It's a topic that's been covered extensively.